# How to fetch a sub ManyToOne property of a fetched ManyToOne property in a default findById?

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entities related by ManyToOne relationships:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cabin_layout")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class CabinLayout {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @JsonIgnore
  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private MissionProfile missionProfile;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "mission_profile")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class MissionProfile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mission_profile_id")
    private Set<FlightRangeShare> flightRangeShares; 

    @JsonIgnore
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private AircraftSeries aircraftSeries;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "aircraft_series")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class AircraftSeries {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AircraftSeriesEnum aircraftSeriesEnum;

}
```

I'm trying to access the `aircraftSeries` sub property of the `missionProfile` property of the `cabinLayout` entity:

```
public int calcProportionalFuelConsumptionInKg(Long cabinLayoutId, FlightRangeEnum flightRangeEnum) {
    return cabinLayoutRepository.findById(cabinLayoutId).map(cabinLayout -> {
    missionProfileRepository.findById(cabinLayout.getMissionProfile().getId()).map(missionProfile -> {
        int aircraftWeightInKg = missionProfile.getAircraftSeries().getAircraftSeriesEnum()
                .getZeroFuelWeightInKg(); // The aircraftWeightInKg is set all right
        aircraftWeightInKg = cabinLayout.getMissionProfile().getAircraftSeries().getAircraftSeriesEnum()
                .getZeroFuelWeightInKg(); // The getAircraftSeries() returns null
        return aircraftWeightInKg;
    })
```

But when doing a findById on a `cabinLayout` entity, it only finds its `missionProfile` property, and it leaves null the `aircraftSeries` sub property.

Only when doing an additional dummy redundant findById on the `missionProfile`, is the `aircraftSeries` property fetched.

The fetching is done one level deep only, with the entity properties fetched, but not the entity properties sub properties.

The debugger on the `cabinLayout` variable shows:

```
id: Long@219
missionProfile: MissionProfile@220 "MissionProfile(id=1, aircraftSeries=null)"
aircraftSeries: null
```

I know the debugger is proxying and not triggering the fetching in its view, so I let run the test until it fails. I can also see the error when running the test in a terminal:

```
2022-10-07 16:30:17,894 ERROR [main] com.exception.ControllerExceptionHandler: Uncatched exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.service.EquipmentCalculatorService.calcEquipmentProportionalFuelConsumptionInKg(EquipmentCalculatorService.java:143)
```

I also tried to have some explicit join and eager fetching and that changed nothing at all.

```
@JsonIgnore
@NotNull
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private MissionProfile missionProfile;

@JsonIgnore
@NotNull
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private AircraftSeries aircraftSeries;
```

The strange thing is that the `missionProfile` entity, has in fact another collection property, that is fetched all right:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "mission_profile_id")
private Set<FlightRangeShare> flightRangeShares;
```

I'm on spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.0 in Java 11

UPDATE: Following the reply from grigouille I created the repository:

```
@Query("SELECT cl FROM CabinLayout cl LEFT JOIN FETCH cl.missionProfile mp LEFT JOIN FETCH mp.aircraftSeries WHERE cl.id = :id")
Optional<CabinLayout> findByIdFetching(@Param("id") Long id);
```

which I called as in:

```
return cabinLayoutRepository.findByIdFetching(cabinLayoutId).map(cabinLayout -> {
```

But it still gives the exact same error.

The log shows the actual SQL statement:

```
 select cabinlayou0_.id as id1_5_0_, missionpro1_.id as id1_18_1_, aircraftse2_.id as id1_1_2_, cabinlayou0_.description as descript2_5_0_, cabinlayou0_.mission_profile_id as mission_7_5_0_, cabinlayou0_.name as name3_5_0_, cabinlayou0_.tags as tags4_5_0_, cabinlayou0_.user_id as user_id5_5_0_, cabinlayou0_.workflow_status_enum as workflow6_5_0_, missionpro1_.aircraft_series_id as aircraft5_18_1_, missionpro1_.flight_cycles as flight_c2_18_1_, missionpro1_.lifetime as lifetime3_18_1_, missionpro1_.name as name4_18_1_, aircraftse2_.aircraft_series_enum as aircraft2_1_2_ from cabin_layout cabinlayou0_ left outer join mission_profile missionpro1_ on cabinlayou0_.mission_profile_id=missionpro1_.id left outer join aircraft_series aircraftse2_ on missionpro1_.aircraft_series_id=aircraftse2_.id where cabinlayou0_.id=?
```

UPDATE: Following a comment I also tried adding the property:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      max_fetch_depth: 3
hibernate:
  max_fetch_depth: 3
```

But it changed nothing.

UPDATE: I tried a workaround with a projection instead.

```
@Query("SELECT new com.domain.projection.CabinLayoutView(cl, mp, ars, ce, e) FROM CabinEquipment ce JOIN ce.equipment e JOIN ce.cabinLayout cl JOIN cl.missionProfile mp JOIN mp.aircraftSeries ars WHERE cl.id = :id")
    List<CabinLayoutView> findByIdFetching(@Param("id") Long id);
```

And then I could reconstruct my entity:

```
public CabinLayout findByIdFetching(Long cabinLayoutId) {
    return toCabinLayout(cabinLayoutRepository.findByIdFetching(cabinLayoutId));
}

private CabinLayout toCabinLayout(List<CabinLayoutView> cabinLayoutViews) {
    if (!cabinLayoutViews.isEmpty()) {
        CabinLayout cabinLayout = null;
        Set<CabinEquipment> cabinEquipments = new HashSet<>();
        for (CabinLayoutView cabinLayoutView : cabinLayoutViews) {
            cabinLayout = cabinLayoutView.getCabinLayout();
            cabinLayout.setMissionProfile(cabinLayoutView.getMissionProfile());
            cabinLayout.getMissionProfile().setAircraftSeries(cabinLayoutView.getAircraftSeries());
            CabinEquipment cabinEquipment = cabinLayoutView.getCabinEquipment();
            cabinEquipment.setEquipment(cabinLayoutView.getEquipment());
            cabinEquipments.add(cabinEquipment);
        }
        if (Objects.nonNull(cabinLayout)) {
            cabinLayout.getCabinEquipments().clear();
            cabinLayout.getCabinEquipments().addAll(cabinEquipments);
        }
        return cabinLayout;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundException("The cabin layout projection was empty");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try fetching all the properties in one query :

```
EntityManager em;
Long id;
CabinLayout cabinLayout = em.createQuery("select c from CabinLayout c left join fetch c.missionProfile m left join fetch m.aircraftSeries where c.id = :id", CabinLayout.class)
  .setParameter("id", id)
  .getSingleResult();
//load flightRangeShares if you want
cabinLayout.getMissionProfile().getFlightRangeShares().size();
return cabinLayout
```

Comment: I had high hopes when reading your reply. But alas it didn't help any. It still gives the same NPE at the same location.

Comment: It seems like it could be that fetch step is fine, but the projection step is only projecting the cabin layout and ignoring the rest that was fetched.

Comment: The links are annotated @NotNull. Are they also NOT NULL in the database ?

Comment: Yes they are. Or they should be. There is no database for now as I'm running the tests in memory using the H2 database.

Comment: I also tried with JOIN FETCH and later on with INNER JOIN FETCH and got the same error.

Comment: May be it has to do with hibernate.max_fetch_depth property.

Comment: Thanks for the good hint. Alas I could not get it to help me. There seems very little out there on using this in a SpringBoot context. And it also feels like this property only matters on default finders like findById and not on custom finders in JPQL containing JOIN FETCH keywords, unless I'm mistaken. I'd love to know more about that though. But for now, I'm still out of luck.